# Android LinearLayout doesn't look the same on an actual device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating a custom digit pad for an Android app. I used several horizontal `LinearLayout` for that.

Here is the code related to that part of the `activity`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="67dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rsz_untitled_3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit4"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit5"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_6" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_9" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digitvoid"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit0"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digitdelete"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Here you can see how this looks like in **Android studio**, and how it looks like on an actual device. I don't understand why is this happening. I am using `dp` (which per my understanding should be dynamic pixels), so they should scale well on every device.

Comment: try to use `ConstraintLayout` you fix this issue simply

Comment: just give all <ImageView> width = 0dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a fixed size on your views, because different phones got different screen size that will make your screen not responsive.

If you want to use `LinearLayout` you will probably want to use `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum` attributes in order to give your views some size relatively to your screen.
You can do this and it will work, but all of the nested views will most likely affect your layouts performance.

If you want a layout that will be responsive to all screen size you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) with [chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html), here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="x"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you do this for the third row:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

And it is causing problems - if your screen is not wide enough to follow your width instruction you instruct that all buttons are not the same so that only the last buttons should be resized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the layout that you need to get this thing working. The dp is translated into approximate sizes. However, if you want to propotionate your elements with the screen size, you might consider using the `weight` all the time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rsz_untitled_3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_9" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitvoid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitdelete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code. It may solve your issue. If you face any issue then please let me know in comment section.

Use your own drawables and assests.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitvoid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitdelete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_more_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please approve answer if it will work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please replace your 4 `LinearLayout` with this :

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/digit1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rsz_untitled_3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit6"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_6" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit7"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit8"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_8" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit9"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_9" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digitvoid"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digit0"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/digitdelete"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add the parent layout this two attribute :

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0"
```

**NB :** 
If you want to reduce the height of the square just reduce value of :`android:layout_weight="0.2"` to `android:layout_weight="0.15"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rsz_untitled_3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_9" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitvoid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digit0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/digitdelete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/digit_delete" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```